# Variable undeclared and primary expression expected

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int amount;
    int newAmount;
    int interestRate;
    int initialAmount;

    cout << "Please enter the dollar amount. "; 
    cin >> amount;            
    cout << "Please enter the interest rate(e.g., nine percent shouold be entered as 9.0). ";
    cin >> interestRate;

    newAmount = FutureValue(amount,interestRate);

    cout << "The new dollar amount is ", newAmount;

    FutureValue(int initialAmount, int interestRate);
    int finalAmount;
    finalAmount = (1 + interestRate/100) * initialAmount;
    return finalAmount;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting 
"19 `FutureValue' undeclared (first use this function)"
"23 expected primary-expression before "int" "
and "23 expected primary-expression before "int" " again

Comment: I guess you expect compiler to declare `FutureValue` for you. That's not gonna happen.

Comment: help. I have changed things, completely rewritten the code and looked over it again and again. I really just need an extra pair of eyes on it. I feel like I'm probably missing something really small but I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @dmortiz Where is `FutureValue`?

Comment: I didn't expect that... I have declared it multiple ways and it always says it can't be defined that way. Which is why I'm here.

Comment: It's used on both lines 19 and 23.

Comment: The psuedocode i was given has it defined on line 23 so the line looked like this: int  FutureValue(int initialAmount, int interestRate);

Comment: ...That's not the question. The question is where is it defined and how is it declared, not where are you using it. We can't help you if we don't know what the function you're trying to use is. The differences between *declaring* a function, *defining* a function, and *using* a function are very important and very basic to the language, and it seems like you really need to review them.

Comment: The line `FutureValue(int initialAmount, int interestRate);` looks like a function declaration, not a function call, so remove the `int `. That is the problem there. The line `cout << "The new dollar amount is ", newAmount;` has a spurious comma, change it to `<<`.  The reason you're getting `FutureValue` is undeclared on line 19 is because it **is** undeclared. You need to declare or `#include` the code for that function before `main`.

Comment: Let me guess `FutureValue` is a function and you have it declared after `main` ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend actually declaring the function, and removing the "declaration" from line 23. You can't declare a function like that, and even if you could, you call it before it is declared which causes an error

```
FutureValue(int initialAmount, int interestRate) // Place whole thing before main
{
     int finalAmount;
     finalAmount = (1 + interestRate/100) * initialAmount;
     return finalAmount;
}
```

or

```
FutureValue(int initialAmount, int interestRate); // Before Main
// Later
FutureValue(int initialAmount, int interestRate) // Place after Main
{
     int finalAmount;
     finalAmount = (1 + interestRate/100) * initialAmount;
     return finalAmount;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I couldn't figure out, was how to write the code correctly before the main. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm a professional when it comes to dealing with aberrations of code :P

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the int from your method call on 23 will fix the second issue. If your method is undeclared make sure you're capitalizing everything correctly and using the correct number of parameters.

Comment: Thank you. But it still gives me the error of FutureValue being undeclared. I have defined it as int, char, float, and everything else I could think of but it always says it can't be used that way.

Comment: It's giving you the error of FutureValue being undeclared because it is undeclared.

Comment: @DimChtz Oh wow I hadn't looked at how he was trying to declare his method.